# What's the role of c != '\n' condition in "for" loop (C language)?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, conditional-statements, character

The input of this function is `s[]` - char array and `lim` - max possible length of this array.

The function itself is used to determine the length of an inputed char array which is entered in the console.

The question is, what's the main idea of `c != '\n'` condition in `for` loop?

I guess it's used to break a loop. It's quite clear. But I can't get how it can be implemented if I don't type `\n` in my input.

Is that a terminator at the end of an array like `\0`?

If that's the case why should we use the `if (c == '\n')` condition after that?

**The code:**

```
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: It is **not** `c! = '\n'` but `c       !=       '\n'`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a `\n` newline character is added to the input buffer, `stdin`, this means that this is the last character in the input buffer.

So it's only fitting the cycle continues on until `getchar()` retrieves this last character.

The cycle control states that `c` must be:

- Different from `\n`.
- Different from`EOF`.
- And the iterator `i` must be lower than `lim - 1`.

If one of these conditions is not met the cycle breaks, so it's possible that `c` is not equal to `\n`.

After that, if `c` is equal to `\n`, it will be added to `s`, the condition `if (c == '\n')` is there because, as stated, `c` might not be equal to `\n`, and in that case it shouldn't be added to `s`.

Lastly `s` must be null terminated (`s[i] = '\0'`) so it can be properly interpreted as a string, aka a null terminated char array. `\n` is not a null terminator, `\0` is.

The fact that `\n` is added is only because the implementer wanted it to be so, it's part of the implementation, it wouldn't have to be, but it is.
 It can be useful in some cases, for instance `fgets` library function has a similar implementation, it adds `\n` to the containing buffer and then null terminates it.

Comment: Thx a lot for the expalnation of internal mechanism. That's what I've been looking for.

Comment: @SoHereWeGo, glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Well you want to get a line. `\0` terminates the string but a string can exist of multiple lines. As the function's name indicates you only want a single line. Lines are terminated with `\n` and after that a new line begins.

Comment: So if I got it in a right way, `\n` is terminated at the end of any line. Then why should we introduce `if` statement after that if any line contains `\n` by default?

Comment: I think the author of the function wanted to preserve `\n`. When the last line is read there is no `\n` at the end of the line. So basically the `\n` is only appended to `s[]` if it was not the last line in the buffer (and the line character limit was not reached).

Comment: Thx a lot it's clear now. Just to clarify this function. Then next step of this program is to copy constructed string in another char array (for camparison with other entered strings and  then print it out if it's the longest one).

Answer (score 3):

The condition

```
c != '\n'
```

is evaluated as `true` if a character different to *new line* character is encountered.

As you can understand, since it is a `getline()` implementation, it is a very good reason to stop reading from the input string.

Please note how, after this check ends the loop `s[i] = '\0';` is executed in order to terminate the string one position after where previously the new line character was.

---

So, how do `getline()` works?

The core of that function is the for-loop

```
for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
```

The condition `i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'` means: *"Assign to `c` a character got with `getchar() until..."*:

- the read character is EOF
- the read character is `\n` (newline)
- the number of characters requested by the caller (`lim`) has been read

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio aaargh! To many "negations" (end too much hurry in writing the answer :) ). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Happens to me often, too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `'\n'`it is only one of the conditions - 
it can be also EOF which author does not want to save and also chars number limit can be reached and we do not want to  write the nul terminator out of the char array bounds

The nul termination is not related to any of those conditions and it always happens

Answer (score 1):

If the character read `c` is a return to new line `\n`, then the `for` loop will stop, and the array will end with `\n` followed by `\0`.

And that's what the function is supposed to do, it's called `getline()`, and lines end with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simply this:

In the `for` loop we're saying that when the user hit `Enter`, stop reading; so it stops and won't read the rest of the input. because the condition `c!='\n'` becomes false.

In the if statement, we're telling the program to continue reading; so "if" the user hits `Enter`, the program will start reading the rest of the input from where it left off and will start looping again.

The if statement is to prevent the loop from stopping and also a way of telling the program that there are separate lines in the input.